# Symfony: Persisting embedded forms and avoiding duplicate entries

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have been playing around with Symfony for about a month now. I like the framework so far, but I have run into a problem which is making me suspicious of the Form component.

**Overview**
I have two forms, one each for the following entities:

- Posts
- Tags

They have a many to many bi-directional relationship. The Tags form is embedded in the Posts form to allow new tags to be created and associated with the post on the fly.

**Problem**
This works just fine with cascade enabled when a new tag entry is used. However, if an existing tag entry is re-used, a unique constraint violation is triggered by the Tags entity. The embedded form basically works as a utility to only create new tags, where as I want to use it in a conditional scenario where existing tags are not inserted but only associated with the parent form.

In a bid to try and avoid duplication issues, I turned off cascade and played around with doctrine listeners. However, I couldn't find a way around it. Does any one have any ideas? I could obviously handle the form submission manually, but that would half-defeat the purpose of using the Form component.

**Form Type**

- Both forms extend "AbstractType"

**Controller**

- The particular action that handles the code looks something like this

  ```
  $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

  $entity = $em->getRepository('B4PGround0Bundle:Blog\\Blog')->find($id);

  if (!$entity) {
      throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Blog entity.');
  }

  $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
  $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
  $editForm->handleRequest($request);

  if ($editForm->isValid()) {
      $em->flush();
  ```

**Entities**

- Excerpt from the **Blog**  class  (Blog is the same as the aforementioned Posts)

  ```
  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag", inversedBy="blogs")
   * @ORM\JoinTable(name="tags_blogs")
   * @Assert\Valid()
   **/
  private $tags;
  .......
  public function addTag($tag)
  {
      $tags->addBlog($this);
      $this->tags[] = $tags;
      return $this
  }
  ```
- Excerpt from the **Tags** class

  ```
  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Blog", mappedBy="tags")
   **/
  private $blogs;
  ....
  public function addBlog($blog)
  {
      $this->blogs[] = $blogs;
      return $this;
  }
  ```

  `

Comment: Can you post your form type? Its a bit difficult to help you without some code. Normally that should work very well and SF2 should only edit the relation table.

Comment: Sure, let me edit the post real quick.

Comment: All done. Took me only about 20 minutes because I somehow managed to break the form here as well, forcing me to write the code down manually for proper indentation. Just that kind of a day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solutiton**

The trick is to subscribe to an event listener and then adjust the persistent collection/UnitOfWork API manually.

**Using doctrine.event_listener**

This should get you started:

[Prevent duplicates in the database in a many-to-many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21280011/symfony2-form-many-to-many-prevent-duplicate-in-database)

**Using doctrine.orm.entity_listener**

The advantage of doing it this way is that the listener is evoked only to the specified entity.

My problem was resolved by subscribing the child to an entity listener, and tackling the duplicates during the 'preFlush' event.

Here's what you have to do:

1. Annotate the entity class (Tag in this case) with the following:

```html
@ORM\EntityListeners({"\PathToListener\TagListener"})
```

2. Here's the bit of code that goes into the event listener (it needs re-factoring, but it should get you started)

```html
/** @ORM\preFlush */ 
public function prePersist(Tag $entities, PreFlushEventArgs $args) 
{ 
    //retrieve the entity manager 
    $em = $args->getEntityManager(); 
    //retrieve the unitOfwork API
    $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();
    //retrieve the child entities repo 
    $tagRepo = $em->getRepository("\Path2ChildEntity\Tag"); 

    //retrieve all the entities scheduled for update 
    foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityUpdates() as $blog) { 

    //we are only interested in handling blog posts 
    if(!($blog instanceof \Path2ParentEntity\Blog))
    { 
      continue; 
    } 

    //retrieve all the tags associated with the blog post entity 
    $tagList = $blog->getTags(); 

    //lets cycle through each retrieved tag, one at a time 
    foreach($tagList as $key=>$tagItem){ 
        
        //lets see if we can find a tag by this name in the repo 
        $tmpTag = $tagRepo->findOneBy(array("name"=>$tagItem->getName()));
        
        //if the tag already exists, we don't want to insert it. 
        if($tmpTag !== null) 
        { 
        //lets cycle through all the entities scheduledd for insertion 
            foreach($uow->getScheduledEntityInsertions() as $items) {
                //if the types match and the names checkout too, remove
the item from the insertion list 

                if(($items instanceof \Path2ChildEntity\Tag) && ($items->getName()===$tmpTag->getName()))
                {
                $uow->remove($items); 
                } 
            } 

        //adjust the blog post entity by replacing the original tag with the one from the database
        $blog->removeTag($tagList[$key]); 
        $tagList[$key] = $tmpTag; 
      } 
    } 
    
    $metadata = $em->getClassMetadata('\Path2ChildEntity\Tag'); 
    //lets ask UOW to recompute the changes that have been made to the Tag and Blog entities since the preFlush event was fired 

    foreach ($tagList as $tag) { 
    $uow->recomputeSingleEntityChangeSet($metadata, $tag); 
    } 

    $metadata = $em->getClassMetadata('\Path2ParentEntity\Blog'); 
    $uow->recomputeSingleEntityChangeSet($metadata, $blog); 
  } 

}
```

Sorry about the messy code guys, but I hope it helps someone out.

PS Since I am new to Doctrine, and still coming to terms with modeling around objects as opposed to tables, I have a sinking feeling my design is to be blamed for the problem I faced. I mean, it shouldn't be this complicated to get something as simple as this going. Either the creators of Symfony missed a trick with embedded forms (less likely) or I still have much to learn about the Object Model.

Comment: Hi @captainspi, I have an equal problem that I can not solve, can you look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34270406/prevent-duplicate-database-with-embedded-forms-symfony2) and help me? since I read your answer but I'm not sure what to do, I'm new to this, thanks.