# Symfony2: How to avoid duplicate entities that already exist in the database?

Tags: php, mysql, entity-framework, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the entities "Student" and "Parents" in two forms, one embedded in another are Symfony2. I need to store data from both entities in different tables of the database, when a new student and his parents also adds added. But I need that parents are not duplicated in the database, so before adding have to check that there are none, add only in that case. I do not know how to do this in Symfony2. More information is another question I asked.

[look the other question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34285413/symfony2-prevent-duplicate-in-database-with-form-many-to-one)

I hope someone can help me because I can not find a solution for this problem.

Comment: is the issue that you are trying to solve same as the one in the other question? if so then this would be a duplicate, which is not allowed on SO. if not, if your just trying to insert unique values into the database then check out my answer

Answer (score 3):

In order to have columns with unique entries you must use UniqueEntity Validation constraint [Docs](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html)

> Validates that a particular field (or fields) in a Doctrine entity is (are) unique. This is commonly used, for example, to prevent a new user to register using an email address that already exists in the system.

add `@UniqueEntity("parent")` above your entity name and `unique=true` on the field that you want to be unique

form the docs

```
// src/AppBundle/Entity/Author.php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

// DON'T forget this use statement!!!
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @UniqueEntity("email")
 */
class Author
{
    /**
     * @var string $email
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     * @Assert\Email()
     */
    protected $email;

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Hi @deeznutz, before I had the code as you indicate, but this does not stop the form introduce a father already existed in the database. In my case even exist in the database can be entered on the form, since parents can have more children. What I need is to check whether there is a father now, and if there is need to keep the student in the database and assign corresponding parents, unregistered these again.