# Prevent duplication in many-to-one relation

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, orm

Using doctrine, I have two entities, one called `Institution` and one called `Location`. Every Institution has one location, but two or more institutions can have the same location. They are linked by a foreign key in `Institution`.

**Institution:**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Location", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $location;
```

**Location:**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=false)
 */
private $renderedLocation;

/**
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=60, unique=true, nullable=false)
 */
private $placeId;
```

When a new institution is added, one is asked for the location of this institution, which saves the `renderedLocation` and the unique `placeId` with help from the Google places API. The form for the `Location` is embedded in the form of `Institution` using symfony forms.

**Form:**

```
    $builder
        ->add('name')
        ->add('location', LocationType::class)
```

After the form submission, a new `Institution` and a new `Location` is saved.

What I would like to achieve is to check if the location entered by the user is perhaps  already in the database, through comparing the unique `placeId`. If this is the case connect the new `Institution` to the already existing `Location`. If not, create the new `Institution` and the new `Location`.

I tried to resolve this issue with the method as described in  [Prevent duplicates in the database in a many-to-many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21280011/prevent-duplicates-in-the-database-in-a-many-to-many-relationship), but with no luck. Even if this did work, it seems like some overkill to use an event listener on all future persists. Any ideas in how to deal with this problem?

**edit**: I did what M Khalid Junaid suggested, and checked for duplication in the form-data. It works, but I have some doubts whether or not this is the correct way. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

**Controller:**

```
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        //....
        $user->addLinkedInstitution($institution);
        $institution = $form->getData();
        $placeId = $institution->getLocation()->getPlaceId();
        $existingLocation = $em->getRepository('App:Location')->checkDuplicate($placeId)->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();
        if ($existingLocation != null){
        $existingPlaceId = $existingLocation->getPlaceId();
        }
        else{
            $existingPlaceId = null;
        }
        if ($placeId == $existingPlaceId)
        {
            $institution->setLocation($existingLocation);
        }
```

Comment: Where you are saving your form data there you could check for dupes and assign existing data

Comment: Could you elaborate? Do you mean in the controller after submitting, but before flushing? Any suggestion how to go about this? Thanks, D

Comment: Did you tried with the UniqueEntity constraint on placeId field?

Comment: I see that you already did. Then simply fetching the location using repository find method is enough imho. Check if the result is empty or not.

Comment: @DirkJ.Faber I mean when you process your form before save just query location data from your database using request values if  there is already data exists for location then assign it else create it, It would be good you can add some related code

Comment: What is the problem to do exactly what you describe? Just check if location exists and connect the institution to the existing location before persist ... using an eventhandler makes sense if you have to ensure, that this logic always happen to your entity independent of forms and controller

Comment: @whitelettersinblankpapers, how would you do this? Because if the result is not empty, you want to replace the inserted data with the existing data.

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid, thanks for your reply. In my controller, this is a part of my form processing: 
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
//......
// set the slug before flushing so the logo filename can be based of the slug.
$institution->setSlug($institution->getInternationalName());
// hold the submitted data.
$institution = $form->getData();
$em->persist($institution);
$em->flush();
}

Comment: @JimPanse, the problem is whenever a user adds a new institution which has a location that already exists in the database, this cannot be saved (thanks to the placeId having to be unique). If the placeId does not have to be unique, the location would be saved twice in the database, and I end up with a duplicate.

Comment: And another problem I have, is that whenever I change the location of an institution, the previous location in the table `Locations` is changed, instead what should happen is a new location should be created, because other institutions might be linked to the previous location.